# Inherited class with different generic type parameters is not castable

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Why is in the following code an instance of `C<B>` *not* castable to `C<A<int>>`, even if `B` *derives* from `A<int>`, even with the covariant `T` in `IC<out T>`?

```
void Main()
{
    var b = new B();
    var c = new C<B>();
    _ = (C<A<int>>)c;
}

class A<T> {
}

class B : A<int> {
}

interface IC<out T> { }

class C<T> : IC<T> {
}
```

Comment: `out T` does not enable you to cast to implementers of `IC`. On the other hand, you can cast to `IC<A<int>>` for example.

Comment: Interfaces can only define public members so they can determine if covariance is correct. Classes don't have that constraint so covariance can't be determined.

Comment: Fundamentally at runtime `C<B>` and `C<A<int>>` are different types, that both derive from the type `C<T>`. This is equivalent to asking why you can't cast an instance of class A to a variable of type B even though they are both objects.